# python how to sum amount of a key based on for loop two lists

Tags: python

I have these two lists:

```py
list1 = [
    {'user_id': 1, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 100},
    {'user_id': 2, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 10000},
    {'user_id': 3, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 200},
    {'user_id': 1, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 200},
    {'user_id': 2, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 110},
    {'user_id': 2, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 40000},
    {'user_id': 3, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 100},
    {'user_id': 3, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 12500},
    {'user_id': 3, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 100},
    {'user_id': 1, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 22500},
]

list2 = [
    {'id': 1},
    {'id': 4},
    {'id': 18},
    {'id': 3},
    {'id': 2},
]
```

Logic is this:

```
if list1['server_id'] == None, it means the user added to the credits. if list1['server_id'] != None, then the user spent money.

if list1['user_id'] == list2['id'], then check if list1['server_id'] == None, sum all of their list1['amount'] and save to a variable called `add_funds`.
if list1['user_id'] == list2['id'], then check if list1['server_id'] != None, sum all of their list1['amount'] and save to a variable called `spent`.

finally, for each user, save a variable called `final_balance = add_funds - spent`. then print `user_id X current balance final_balance.`
```

This is my code but I know it's incorrect:

```py
tmp = []
for l2 in list2:
    for l1 in list1:
        spent = 0
        add_fund = 0
        if l1['user_id'] == l2['id'] and l1['user_id'] not in tmp:
            tmp.append(l1['user_id'])
            if l1['server_id'] == None:
                add_fund += l1['amount']
            elif l1['server_id'] != None:
                spent += l1['amount']
        final_balance = add_fund - spent
        if final_balance > 0:
            print(f"User{l1['user_id']} spent {format(spent, ',d').replace(',',',')}, add_funds {format(add_fund, ',d').replace(',',',')}, final_balance {format(final_balance, ',d').replace(',',',')}")
```

This is my current output:

```
User4 spent 0, add_funds 85,700, final_balance 85,700
User4 spent 0, add_funds 10,000, final_balance 10,000
```

I know these are my issues in this code:

1. I'm assigning 0 to spent at each iteration and if the next two IDs don't match, it's going to 0 again. Also the last sentence is correct for add_fund too.

This should be the correct output I'm trying to reach:

```
User1 spent 300, add_funds 22,500, final_balance 22,200
User2 spent 110, add_funds 50,000, final_balance 49,890
User3 spent 400, add_funds 12,500, final_balance 12,100
```

Comment: Can you please provide a smaller sample so that we can test?

Comment: @MrIrrelevant sure, I'll edit the question soon.

Comment: @MrIrrelevant it's edited.

Comment: What is the purpose of list2 ?

Comment: @CtrlZ in the real-world example, I have these two lists (I mean I create these two lists myself). But you're right, the `list1` is enough, and you can ignore the `list2`. I also can remove the `list2` in my real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the correct calculation of funds added, spent, and the final balance for each user, you can follow these steps:

1. Iterate through the list containing user IDs.
2. For each user, filter their transactions from the list containing transaction details.
3. Sum the amount for transactions where server_id is None to calculate add_funds.
4. Sum the amount for transactions where server_id is not None to calculate spent.
5. Calculate final_balance for each user as add_funds - spent.
   Store and print the results.

```py
list1 = [
    # Your transactions list
]

list2 = [
    # Your user IDs list
]

user_balances = {}

for user in list2:
    user_id = user['id']
    add_funds = sum(item['amount'] for item in list1 if item['user_id'] == user_id and item['server_id'] is None)
    spent = sum(item['amount'] for item in list1 if item['user_id'] == user_id and item['server_id'] is not None)
    final_balance = add_funds - spent
    
    if add_funds or spent:
        user_balances[user_id] = {'spent': spent, 'add_funds': add_funds, 'final_balance': final_balance}

for user_id, balances in user_balances.items():
    print(f"User {user_id} spent {balances['spent']}, added funds {balances['add_funds']}, final balance {balances['final_balance']}")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't have enough reputation to upvote:( But thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer when the output differs from the stated requirement

Comment: @CtrlZ oops, I'll check again:( It seems it was correct.

Comment: @CtrlZ what's the issue of this code? I ran and the output is as expected.

Comment: @Rogers The output is not exactly as you had stated as being the requirement

Comment: @CtrlZ you mean the thousand separator? If yes, that doesn't matter because that is a way of styling the output. But if you mean the numbers are incorrect or code is wrong, can you advise the wrong part?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this solution would be more reliable, but it's kind of harder to understand. Basically it uses `filter` function to only get a subset of all records in `list1` (I filter transactions of the current user, and I filter transactions that add or subtract funds). Then it uses `map` function to convert one transaction data (e.g. `{'user_id': 1, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 22500}` to just the amount -> `22500`). Then the values are summed up with `sum`

```
def format_money(num):
    return format(num, ',d').replace(',',',') 

for user in list2:
    uid = user['id']
    
    transactions = list(filter(lambda t: t.get('user_id') == uid, list1))
    total_funded = sum(
        map(lambda t: t.get('amount'), 
        filter(lambda t: t.get('server_id') is None, transactions)))
    total_spent = sum(
        map(lambda t: t.get('amount'), 
        filter(lambda t: t.get('server_id') is not None, transactions)))
    final_balance = total_funded - total_spent
    if final_balance > 0:
       print(f"User{uid} spent {format_money(total_spent)}, add_funds {format_money(total_funded)}, final_balance {format_money(final_balance)}")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this also , use `dict` to store data while iterating

```
list1 = [
    {'user_id': 1, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 100},
    {'user_id': 2, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 10000},
    {'user_id': 3, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 200},
    {'user_id': 1, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 200},
    {'user_id': 2, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 110},
    {'user_id': 2, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 40000},
    {'user_id': 3, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 100},
    {'user_id': 3, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 12500},
    {'user_id': 3, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 100},
    {'user_id': 1, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 22500},
]


result = {
            "user_id": None,
            
                "added": 0,
                "spent": 0,
                "total":0
            
}
from copy import copy

sol = {}

for user_data in list1:
    user_id = user_data['user_id']
    if user_id not in sol:
        sol[user_id] = copy(result)
        sol[user_id]['user_id'] = user_id
    if user_data['server_id'] == None:
        sol[user_id]["added"] += user_data['amount']
    elif user_data['server_id'] != None:
        sol[user_id]['spent'] += user_data['amount']
    sol[user_id]['total'] = sol[user_id]['added'] - sol[user_id]['spent']


print(sol)
```

output

```
{
    1: {'user_id': 1, 'added': 22500, 'spent': 300, 'total': 22200},
    2: {'user_id': 2, 'added': 50000, 'spent': 110, 'total': 49890},
    3: {'user_id': 3, 'added': 12500, 'spent': 400, 'total': 12100}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [
    {'user_id': 1, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 100},
    {'user_id': 2, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 10000},
    {'user_id': 3, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 200},
    {'user_id': 1, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 200},
    {'user_id': 2, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 110},
    {'user_id': 2, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 40000},
    {'user_id': 3, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 100},
    {'user_id': 3, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 12500},
    {'user_id': 3, 'server_id': '10', 'amount': 100},
    {'user_id': 1, 'server_id': None, 'amount': 22500},
]

list2 = [
    {'id': 1},
    {'id': 4},
    {'id': 18},
    {'id': 3},
    {'id': 2},
]

# Create two dict named add_funds and spent
add_funds = {}
spent = {}

# iterate thru list2
for  x in list2:
    add_sum, spent_sum = 0, 0
    
    # iterate thru list1    
    for y in list1:
    
        # If user id and the id match
        if y['user_id'] == x['id']:
        
            # If server id is none,  add amount to add_sum
            if y['server_id'] == None:
                add_sum = add_sum + y['amount']

            # else add amount to spent_sum
            else:
                spent_sum = spent_sum + y['amount']
    
    # if the total of add_sum is not zero
    if add_sum != 0:
        add_funds[x['id']] = add_sum
        
    # if the total of spent_sum is not zero
    if spent_sum != 0:
        spent[x['id']] = spent_sum

final_balance = {}

#subtract values
for k, v in add_funds.items():
    final_balance[k] = v - spent[k]       
            
print(final_balance) # Output: {1: 22200, 3: 12100, 2: 49890}
```

Answer (score 1):

Build an intermediate dictionary to store the accumulated deposits and withdrawals:

```
list1 = [
    {"user_id": 1, "server_id": "10", "amount": 100},
    {"user_id": 2, "server_id": None, "amount": 10000},
    {"user_id": 3, "server_id": "10", "amount": 200},
    {"user_id": 1, "server_id": "10", "amount": 200},
    {"user_id": 2, "server_id": "10", "amount": 110},
    {"user_id": 2, "server_id": None, "amount": 40000},
    {"user_id": 3, "server_id": "10", "amount": 100},
    {"user_id": 3, "server_id": None, "amount": 12500},
    {"user_id": 3, "server_id": "10", "amount": 100},
    {"user_id": 1, "server_id": None, "amount": 22500},
]


results = dict()

for d in list1:
    rd = results.setdefault(d["user_id"], [0, 0])
    i = 1 if d.get("server_id") is None else 0
    rd[i] += d["amount"]

for k, v in results.items():
    _out, _in = v
    _bal = _in - _out
    print(f"User{k} spent {_out:,}, add_funds {_in:,}, final_balance {_bal:,}")
```

**Output:**

```
User1 spent 300, add_funds 22,500, final_balance 22,200
User2 spent 110, add_funds 50,000, final_balance 49,890
User3 spent 400, add_funds 12,500, final_balance 12,100
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am a little late to the party but list comprehension does work well here, as a previous answer mentioned. This one is a little different.

1. Get the user id list Sort it.
2. For each user id, get the data.
3. If there is data for that user, do a list comprehension to get spent
   data.
4. Get add_funds through list comprehension.
5. Get final balance.
6. Print.

```py
list2_ids = [r['id'] for r in list2]
list2_ids.sort()

for user_id in list2_ids:
    data_for_user = [r for r in list1 if r['user_id'] == user_id]
    if (len(data_for_user)):
        spent = sum([r['amount'] for r in data_for_user if r['server_id'] != None])
        add_funds = sum([r['amount'] for r in data_for_user if r['server_id'] == None])
        final_balance = add_funds - spent
        print(f"User{user_id} spent {format(spent, ',d')}, add_funds {format(add_funds, ',d')}, final_balance {format(final_balance, ',d')}")
```